# Export PATH in terminal

Tags: unix, terminal

Every time I need to add a new `PATH` in my `bash_profile` I just append it to my old path using something like

```
PATH=$PATH:.....
```

Then I export `PATH` at the end.

If I wanted to add another path and left out the above and just created a new path, would it reset the path to just this new path?

If I exported the `PATH` before the new path would it not even reach the new `PATH`?

Comment: Once exported, it should stay current.  Why not just make an experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~]$ export PATH=/bin
~]$ echo $PATH
/bin

~]$ export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
~]$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

~]$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin
~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make an export of the PATH it will live only in the current session. The changes into the bash_profile will be permanent, and take effect after restarting the terminal.

So if you export the PATH with the new content, it doesn't mind what content it has into the bash_profile, because you will overwrite it. But when you restart the session, it will have the content of the bash_profile file.

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: You could `source ` instead of restart.

Answer (score 0):

you use `export` to make a local shell variable global. Meaning, to make a shell variable available across inherited sub shell sessions.

Hence it is enough to `export` a shell variable just once. You can alter the values as you wish without `export`ing it again.

[Read more here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059)